# How to bind css style from TypeScript method with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component like this below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-item',
  templateUrl: './car-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-item.component.css'],
})
export class CarItemComponent {
  public style: string

  addStyle() {
    this.style = 'font-size: 20px'
  }
```

How can I implement `addStyle()` method to change size of font in car-item.component.css?

Comment: I believe you are best using the ngStyle directive to pass an object from your html element to your typescript (conditionally if you wish)

Comment: Or you can use ViewChild directive to access the element of interest in your DOM and apply a style that way

Answer (score 5):

This is not how you do it in Angular! This is how you would do it:

In your `CarItemComponent` add a vairable for the font-size for example:

```
fontSize: number;
```

In your `addStyle()` set this number to the font size you want to use and in your template add this to the element which's font-size you want to change:

```
[style.font-size.px]="{{ fontSize }}"
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie in Angular. Where exactly do I have to add this line: [style.font-size.px]="{{ fontSize }}" ?

Comment: In your template on the element whichs font-size you want to change: <div [style.font-size.px]="{{ fontSize }}">content</div>

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful (Angular 6):

1. Change styles in order to look like disabled
2. Eliminate the href

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzgr4h